# I would like to know about the implementation of sending an SMS through oracle pl/Sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, sms

I would like to know about the implementation of sending an SMS through oracle pl/Sql.If any one who has developed please provide an input.

Comment: SO is intended for detailed questions on specific programming problems; questions like "I need to do this, please help" are considered off-topic.

Comment: As I know you cannot do this by use pl/sql procedure but maybe you can use the oracle java procedure to implement this.

Comment: It should be able to use oracle db package utl_mail to send an email to the sms-gateway and this sms-gateway should be able to convert this email into an sms. I don't think that a Java stored procedure is needed.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you some ideas, using this function i can send sms using soap api of sms service, you should tune it using your soap envelope, response, ip wallet etc.
Input should be xml data according to your service putted together with envelope - you need to consult this with your provider.

Of course if you user modern oracle you should ensure about ACL for IP and network access as well as encryption for your connection

```
function send(message_data in varchar2) return varchar2 is
/**************************************************
* author: jareeq
* use as you like
***************************************************/
  resp             sys.xmltype;
  http_req         utl_http.req;
  http_resp        utl_http.resp;
  soap_request     clob;
  soap_respond     clob;
  v_result         varchar2(4096);
  v_buffer_varchar varchar2(4096);

begin
/* wallet for https con */
  UTL_HTTP.set_wallet('file:/xxx/xxx/xxx/wallets', '************');
  soap_request := '<your soap envelope here>';
  utl_http.set_response_error_check(TRUE);
  http_req := utl_http.begin_request('https://<your service request>',
                                     'POST', 'HTTP/1.1');
  utl_http.set_header(http_req, 'Content-Type',
                      'application/xop+xml; type=text/xml; charset=utf-8');
  utl_http.set_header(http_req, 'Content-Length', length(soap_request));
  utl_http.write_text(http_req, soap_request);
  http_resp := utl_http.get_response(http_req);

  begin
    loop
      utl_http.read_text(http_resp, v_buffer_varchar);
      soap_respond := soap_respond || v_buffer_varchar;
    end loop;
    utl_http.end_response(http_resp);
  exception
    when utl_http.end_of_body then
      utl_http.end_response(http_resp);
  end;
  utl_http.close_persistent_conns('<your connection ip>', 443);
  resp     := sys.xmltype.createXML(soap_respond);
  v_result := resp.extract('<your extraction path>')
              .getStringVal();
    return replace(replace(v_result,chr(10)),chr(13));

exception
  when utl_http.end_of_body then
    utl_http.end_response(http_resp);
    utl_http.close_persistent_conns('<your connection ip>', 443);
    return replace(replace(v_result,chr(10)),chr(13));
end send;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike email, Oracle provides no API for sending messages via SMS. However, you can use UTL_HTTP to send requests to an SMS Gateway, depending on what types of APIs they offer you. You will find some offer HTTP, SOAP, and Rest-style APIs, as well as Email-to-SMS.

Personally I use a local gateway here in Australia (ClickSend) that suits my needs. They offer a REST-style API which is quite easy to call using UTL_HTTP.

Find a gateway that suits your needs and budget first. They vary as well in quality of service - some are just Tier 2 aggregators so SMS's can take a while to get through; Tier 1 will have direct connections or premium agreements with a number of mobile carriers for fast delivery.